# Python - Parallelism not working

Tags: python, parallel-processing

EDIT: I got good feedback in the comments.  Made some changes to the code, but am still seeing a similar issue.  Now it seems something is wrong with how I'm timing, because the second operation takes more than 0 seconds.

ORIGINAL:
I've written code that is ostensibly parallel but does not actually run any faster - both parallel and non-parallel versions take the same amount of time.  For the life of me I can't figure out why.

I am using Python 3.4 via Anaconda on Windows 7.  The results are the same whether I submit the job in the IDE (Spyder) or the Command Prompt.  Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def divide_by_two(n):
    time.sleep(.1)
    return n/2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("The number of cores is ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    smallList = range(0,1000) #[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    print('Checking the parallelized way', smallList[:5])
    start = time.time()
    result = pool.map(divide_by_two, smallList)
    end = time.time()
    cleaned = [x for x in result if not x is None]
    print('small List divided by two is ', str(cleaned[:5]))
    print('Parallel way takes ', str(end-start), ' seconds')

    #Now the dumb version
    print('Checking the slow way', smallList[:5])
    start2 = time.time()
    smallList = range(0,1000) #[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    result2 = map(divide_by_two, smallList)
    end2 = time.time()
    cleaned2 = [x for x in result2 if not x is None]
    print('small List divided by two is ', str(cleaned2[:5]))
    print('The slow way takes', str(end2-start2), ' seconds')
```

Here is the output:

```
The number of cores is  4
Checking the parallelized way range(0, 5)
small List divided by two is  [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
Parallel way takes  26.87681818008423  seconds
Checking the slow way range(0, 5)
small List divided by two is  [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
The slow way takes 0.0  seconds
```

Comment: There is a always a small overhead when multiprocessing in python. When you run it for such small tasks the difference is negligible. It is only when you implement it on larger sets of data will you get improvement in speeds

Comment: Your tasks are too small. Try with more time consuming functions instead of the sleep.

Comment: Seems you are using the wrong `start` time on your second print statement.

Comment: interestingly on my mac running python 2.7 parallel execution takes 1.02 secs while 'slow' takes almost 7 seconds

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Fixed start end and increased number of operations, but am now getting a timing problem, making it hard to see if it's working now.  More thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenters.  Would upvote comments if I could.  Increased size of parallelized problem, used the right variables this time (oops!) and used different timing functions.  Here it is:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def divide_by_two(n):
    time.sleep(.1)
    return n/2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("The number of cores is ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    smallList = range(0,1000) #[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    print('Checking the parallelized way', smallList[:5])
    start = time.clock() #time.time()
    print('Start 1 is ', start)
    result = pool.map(divide_by_two, smallList)
    end = time.time()
    cleaned = [x for x in result if not x is None]
    print('small List divided by two is ', str(cleaned[:5]))
    print('Parallel way takes ', time.clock()-start, ' seconds')    

    #Now the dumb version
    print('Checking the slow way', smallList[:5])
    start = time.clock()
    print('Start 2 is ', start)
    result2 = map(divide_by_two, smallList)
    cleaned2 = [x for x in result2 if not x is None]
    print('small List divided by two is ', str(cleaned2[:5]))
    print('The slow way takes', time.clock()-start, ' seconds')
```